# How do I break axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

In R

I have the ageadjustet incidence rates on my y-axis and I want to plot them against the calender years on my x-axis.

I have to following:

```
library(ggplot2)

kkj <- ggplot(d, aes(d$year)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.pap), colour="red") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.fol), colour="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.ana), colour="yellow") +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.med), colour="black") 

kkj1 <- kkj + ylab("Ageadjustet IR") + xlab("Years") 

kkj1
```

My ageadjustet incidence rates are ranging between 0.00 and 5.00 and my calender years are between 1980 and 2014.

I want to break my y-axis by 0.25 and by x-axis by 5-years. Can't seem to figure it out - can you help?

Okay - so this worked:

```
library(ggplot2)

kkj <- ggplot(d, aes(d$year)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.pap), colour="red") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.fol), colour="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.ana), colour="yellow") +
  geom_line(aes(y=d$aair.med), colour="black") 

kkj1 <- kkj + scale_x_continuous(name="Years",breaks = c(1980, 1985, 
1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015), limits = c(1980,2015))+ 
scale_y_continuous(name="Ageadjustet incidence rates per 
100.000",breaks 
=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25,3.5,3.75,4), 
limits = c(0,4))
```

How do I add a label to the "red, green, yellow and black"-line in my plot saying "papillary carcinoma, follicular carcinoma, anaplastic carcinoma and medullary carcinoma" ?
C.

Comment: `?scale_y_continuous`  & `?scale_x_date` both have `breaks` / `date_breaks` and `labels` / `date_labels` (respectively). There's great help on them + many examples on SO and all over the web. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Thank you - it worked! Please see my edited question! Thanks :)

Comment: `?geom_text()` or `?geom_label()` using a separate data frame for the `data` parameter **or** `?annotate()` (follow the example there for the "text" annotation)